# Подскажите, а это нормально, что любое приложение на Windows может в любое время сканировать буфер обмена?

Tags: безопасность

То есть любое приложение может в любой момент обновиться с функцией сканирования буфера и отправки его на любой сервер? А это ведь почти половина обрабатываемой пользователем информации! Или это как-то будет идентифицироваться как вирус Windows Defenderом?

Comment: Ну, любое приложение может и почти любые файлы прочесть и их содержимое куда-то отправить. Некоторые системные утилиты Windows так и делают....

Comment: то есть если у вас есть хоть что-нибудь мало-мальски важное (начиная от клиентской базы) - единственный вариант вообще не подключаться к интернету?

Comment: У нас клиентские базы лежат на серверах, не подключенных к внешней сети

Comment: это хорошо, но обрабатываемая сотрудником информация, полученная оттуда может потихоньку утекать?

Comment: Это зависит от того, как у вас поставлена работа с данными